# how can i get periodicity of random function in c++

Tags: c++

I want to calculate pattern at which stage random numbers repeat

```
               string a="abcd";

               for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
               {
               a=swap(a[i%4],a[rand()]%4)
               cout<<a<<"\n";
               }
```

I want to calculate the stage at which, string pattern will same

Comment: a[i] is only valid for i=0 to i=3. You have i going to 9999, you will exceed the boundary of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Most random number generators' sequences do not repeat on successive calls to rand, and can pass tests for randomness.
The actual algorithm used in your C++ implementation can vary, and can be one of the algorithms listed here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Each has its own theory and implementation.

For example, the generation of one of the most common ones the Linear Congruential , is explained here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

It is important to note that most C++ random number generators will generate the same sequence of numbers on different runs of the application, when seeded with the same seed.